# The region asia-south1 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

In trying to deploy a laravel project to a flexible environment in App Engine, I was hit with this message.
It has been two days now, any way to solve this while maintaining the same region for my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting old versions of your deployment and/or consider reducing the resources you may need for your deploys (including `max_instances`). If you can't change this I think you should wait until there are resources or change your project to another region.

In addition, if your applications allows it, you can try on App Engine Standard Environment which does not use a VM in Compute Engine as the backend being this is my opinion the best option to maintain the same region for your project.

Comment: I can't use Standard Environment because of the nature of the app, has to be flexible.
`max_instances` is already set at 1 for me. I tried deleting old versions of the deployment, and that didn't help.  It would be beneficial for me to keep the app in the same region since all users are in India.

Now the error is intermittent. Shame that google is not proving good support on this. It's really killing my development speed. Thanks for the help.